# In Pelican, how can I link an image to its fullsize version?

Tags: blogs, pelican

In my Pelican blog article I have something like this:

```
![Alt Text]({filename}/images/foo.jpg)
```

This works fine as it includes foo.jpg into the article, i.e., it creates

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="Alt Text">
```

However, I'd like to make this image clickable so users can link the image to go to a URL for the full-size image, i.e.

```
<a href="/images/foo.jpg"><img src="/images/foo.jpg" alt="Alt Text"></a>
```

How can I do that in Pelican?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
[![Alt Text]({filename}/images/foo.jpg)]({filename}/images/foo.jpg)
```

... or:

```
[<img src="{filename}/images/foo.jpg">]({filename}/images/foo.jpg)
```

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38915/creating-an-image-link-in-markdown-format

Answer (score -1):

Did you try dropping the HTML directly into the Markdown file? It'll work just fine.

Comment: this is not a recommended way of `pelican`-life ;)

Comment: Unless you need to specify the width.