# Using ReST syntax with Pelican, how would I have my images within figures clickable to full-size?

Tags: image, restructuredtext, pelican

I checked through the existing posts relating to this, as per [linking an image to its fullsize image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24983810/in-pelican-how-can-i-link-an-image-to-its-fullsize-version), but that is a) not really answered, and b) using Markdown.

I prefer to use ReST because of it's figure support. This means that I can use the [Better Figures and Images plugin](http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/05/29/better-figures-images-plugin-for-pelican/) and have brief captions below my images. Given that I'm using my website mostly for a user experience portfolio, this is a must.

This page about [enlarging images using CSS and javascript](http://livven.me/2012/04/27/how-to-enlarge-images-on-click-using-css-and-javascript/) seems almost right, except for the part where I'm not completely sure how to integrate it with pelican. Thus far, I've put the *img.expanded* CSS into the style.css file below the *.figure img {}* section, as *.figure img.expanded*:

```
.figure img {
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-shadow: none;
}

/* enlarge on click */
.figure img.expanded {
max-width: none;
}
```

---

And I put the javascript bit into the base.html template, near the bottom of the head section, but before the endblock:

```
  <!-- expand images -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       var imageLinks = $('a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".gif"], a[href$=".bmp"]');
       if (imageLinks.children('img').length) {
         imageLinks.children('img').each(function() {
            var currentTitle = $(this).attr('title');
            $(this).attr('title', currentTitle + ' (click to enlarge image)');
         });
         imageLinks.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).children('img').toggleClass('expanded');
         });
       }
     });
  </script>
  {% endblock %}
  </head>
```

---

However, I'm now stuck on how I'd make the images within the figure clickable. The first image on https://suzannehillman.com/pages/fedora-regional-hubs.html currently has the following code:

```
  .. figure:: {filename}/images/competitive_ss.png
     :width: 400px
     :alt: Competitive analysis
     :figclass: center

     Sample of the analysis spreadsheet
```

I *think* I need to figure out how to make the image inside the figure link to itself?

Mind you, I have no idea if what I have already done will actually work, given that I can't test it without an expandable link to click on.

Comment: If ReST's `figure` directive allowed you to add a particular CSS class for images, then you could write a Javascript that (on page ready) selects all images that have that particular class set and that adds the right on-click behaviour (because you now know the image URL). Basically, instead of adding the on-click behaviour while generating the site, you add it once it has been loaded.

Comment: Malte: This is an interesting idea. I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing that, though! I know that I can specify image classes (indeed, I have above with 'figclass'). I'm not hugely familiar with Javascript, though.

Comment: Seeing `$` in your Javascript snippet, I assume that you use jQuery. In that case, have a look at their docs: they are quite extensive and contain lots of examples of selecting HTML nodes based on various criteria, including CSS classes, and how to modify selected nodes.